# A container for holding different class objects

Tags: c++

I have a code, which contains 4 different classes.
I have to create method insert, which holds somewhere the objects. But I don't know how to achieve that.

So I can create insert method for all types of object but how to store them?
Because I cannot create one type array for it. I have to do this without templates.

```
   int main ()
    {
       List all;
       all.insert(new Number (30.1));
      //
       Number num1 (30.0);
       all.insert(num1);
      //
       IntArray a_int (3);
       all.insert(a_int);
      //
       FloatArray a_float (4);
       all.insert(a_float);
      //
       all.PrintAll();
    }
    /*
    Output for PrintAll:
    Number: 30.1
    Number: 30.0
    IntArray: 3
    FloatArray: 4
    */
```

Comment: If this is an assignment for a programming class, please give the exact text of the assignment.  Your interpretation of an assignment you don't understand is of limited usefulness.  If it is not an assignment for a programming class, please justify your restrictions ("I have to do this without templates").

Comment: Wrong choise of programming language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two ways to do this without templates:

1) Implement a container object (like QVariant) that includes member variables for each possible class. Then simply store instances of these containers to your array. The container could have e.g. an enum that indicates which of the members is set.

2) Inherit the classes from a same base class and store pointers to the base class to your array.